# access localhost from other PC

Tags: networking

I'm fresher for ubuntu 12.04..,
I just created a simple program called login.php
and i would like to run this prog from anther PC that not in my LAN.
I had localhost in my system., I'm using apache2.0 and php5.
My program is located at var/www/login.php

When ever i'm trying to open it from others PC(not in my network) using IP it shoes OOPS.,

What can i do to open my page from another PC using IP address.

One thing i need to say, i.e., I already run my program in other systems those in my LAN.,
by using my IP like 192.168.xx.xx/login.php ., It works. But my question is what about from another systems that not in my LAN.
Simply my requirement is to run my database from others PC through IP..
Is it possible. All of my friends said that it is not possible from outside of the LAN

Comment: this is a very poorly structured question. I think your having problems with networking and not with PHP or apache. Can you verify that you can "ping" the host machine?

Comment: thanks for your response. One thing i need to say, i.e., I already run my program in other systems those in my LAN.,
by using my IP like 192.168.xx.xx/login.php ., It works. But my question is what about from another systems that not in my LAN.
Simply my requirement is to run my database from others PC through IP..
Is it possible. All of my friends said that it is not possible from outside of the LAN

Comment: Enable port forwarding in your router so that your server takes and gives connections through port 80. From there, you use your external IP to access it from outside your network.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to set up your router to route http requests to your IP to your specific machine on the LAN.

The way this is done depends on your router make/model.